# Magento2, display tax rate on product page through xml file

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I'm trying to display the tax rate on product page in same container as price . Where to place  `$_product->getAttributeText('tax_class_id')` ?

Edit:

In `myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`this
`<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('tax_class_id‌​')); ?>`returns the value . But how to move it in `product-info-price` or after it?`

Comment: you can try with $block->getAtCode() in your template file;

Comment: I edited my question...I appreciate if you provide any hint

Comment: at which point you want to show tax rate?

Comment: <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review"> I want to have it here "product-info-price" of after it if possible

Comment: Have you got value for above taxrate?

Comment: Yeap, I was able to display it in category list, but have difficulty in product page

Comment: You have to check for first get tax rate on product and after you can set at your proper location

Comment: <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('tax_class_id')); ?> returns the value if I have it in attribute.phtml. But how to move it in product-info-price or after it?

Comment: in which file you have called above statement?

Comment: ....templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

Comment: You can try with below code in your theme or module, I havent try that.

Answer (score 1):

call inside tax.phtml file,

```
<?php 
$_product = $block->getProduct();
echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('tax_class_id‌​')); ?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error:Call to a member function getSource() on boolean..../magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php:1696

Comment: I figured out the xml ;) tnx, please remove your xml part and I vote your hint

Comment: I have removed code of xml

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xml part solution:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.price">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.taxclass"
                   template="product/view/tax.phtml" after="-" >
            </block>
 </referenceContainer>
```